# nltk module installation in pip through cmd

Tags: python-2.7, pip

When I tried to run this **command**:

```
c:\python27\scripts\pip install nltk-3.2.1-py2.py3-none-any
```

I am getting  the **error**:

```
no matching distribution found 
Although i have installed nltk from 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#nltk
```

Kindly help.

I am working on *Windows 8 64-bit Version*

Comment: why don't you just do `pip install nltk`.

Answer (score 1):

Installing new modules can be a nightmare if you are new to Python.First delete any old versions of NLTK if already installed. Open cmd navigate to `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts`, the default directory, using the command `cd path_name_comes_here`. Otherwise goto the path where you have installed python and goto the `Scripts` subfolder and use this path here onwards. Now the most preferred way is to use `pip install module_you_want_to_install` for anything in python. `Pip` automatically fetches everything it needs to install said module.

- Simply use `pip install nltk`.
- Another method is to use `easy_install requirement_or_URL`.
- Some rare occasions its best to download the wheel from `http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs` and from there you can simply use `pip install downloaded_wheel_name` again. But make sure to copy the name of the wheel EXACTLY.

Post installation make sure that your package is accessible from `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\site-packages` or a similar path depending on where you installed python.

Answer (score 0):

> Try Anaconda - Instead . Always works

C:\Users\sanan>conda install -c anaconda nltk
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\sanan\Miniconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

```
nltk:      3.2.4-py36_0  anaconda
```

The following packages will be UPDATED:

```
conda:     4.3.23-py36_0          --> 4.3.25-py36_0 anaconda
```

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

```
conda-env: 2.6.0-0                --> 2.6.0-0       anaconda
```

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

conda-env-2.6. 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00  22.84 kB/s
nltk-3.2.4-py3 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:02 774.24 kB/s
conda-4.3.25-p 100% |###############################| Time: 0:00:00 578.90 kB/s

After installation is complete .

```
import nltk
print(nltk.__version__)
```

C:\Public\Code\textnorm>python attempt1.py
**3.2.4**